# How do I get a query result into a textfield?

Tags: vba, ms-access, textfield

I am creating an accounting database.
For the financial results, my form has a textfield ("Previous Solde") where the solde of previous months is shown. That exact amount is calculated with this query:

```
SELECT      [sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo].Account, 
            Sum([sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo].SomVanBedrag) AS SomVanSomVanBedrag 
FROM        [sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo] 
WHERE       (((Year([Boekdatum]) & "/" & Month([Boekdatum]))<"2022/6")) 
GROUP BY    [sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo].Account 
HAVING      ((([sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo].Account)="BE61973184860917"));
```

The account number ("BE61973184860917") and the closing date ("2022/6") of course are replaced with variables.
The query does exactly what I want it to do.
When I run this query in Access, I get the expected result.
The question is: how do I get the result of the query into the textfield (Previous Solde) on the form?

Answer (score 0):

Could simplify that SQL

```
SELECT Sum([sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo].SomVanBedrag) AS SomVanSomVanBedrag 
FROM [sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo] 
WHERE Format([Boekdatum], "yyyy/mm") < "2022/06"
     AND [sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo].Account = "BE61973184860917";
```

Then use DLookup() domain aggregate function expression in textbox to pull from that query.
`=DLookup("SomVanSomVanBedrag", "queryname")`

Or don't use query and instead use DSum() domain aggregate function expression in textbox.

```
=DSum("SomVanBedrag", "sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo", 
      "Format(Boekdatum, 'yyyy/mm') < '2022/06' AND Account = 'BE61973184860917'")
```

Note the use of placeholder zero in the month part. Without it, records will not filter/sort correctly - `2022/12` would be less than `2022/6`. This means query run in December would not retrieve Feb - Sep data for that same year. Even if the value is structured as a number without the /, the 0 would be needed. If users are selecting from a combobox, make sure values include placeholder 0 for 2-digit month.

Answer (score 0):

The simple method is to use `DSum` in the *ControlSource* of that textbox.

To include your parameters from, I guess, two other textboxes named, say, `txtDatum` and `txtAccount` holding the values `BE61973184860917` and `2022/6`:

```vb
=DSum("[SomVanBedrag]","[sq Argenta Prep Vorig Saldo]","[Boekdatum] < DateValue(" & [txtDatum] & ") And [Account] = '" & [txtAccount] & "'")
```